Failed to remove line numbers in pnas paper overleaf template
I tried every available ways online to remove line numbers but failed. Can someone help? Here is the template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-research-report-submission-to-pnas-using-overleaf-2023/whbdryzwztnd

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a link to a file.
